# Preventing multiple definition in C++

Tags: c++, g++, multiple-definition-error

I am getting error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCbt8ru.o: in function `some_function()':
Thing.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `some_function()'; /tmp/ccc0uW5u.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when building a program like this:

---

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "common.hpp"
#include "Thing.hpp"

int main() {
    some_function();
}
```

**common.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

void some_function() {
    std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
}
```

**Thing.hpp**

```
#pragma once

class Thing {
public:
    void do_something();
};
```

**Thing.cpp**

```
#include "Thing.hpp"
#include "common.hpp"

void Thing::do_something() {
    some_function();
}
```

---

I'm compiling with: `g++ main.cpp Thing.cpp -o main.out`

I've also tried using include guards instead of `#pragma once`, but it didn't seem to work either. Is there something I am forgetting here?

Comment: Include guards prevent multiple inclusions of a header in a single cpp file (technical term: translation unit). You have multiple cpp files. Each includes. Each gets its own definition of `some_function`. Consider making `some_function` `inline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#pragma once` and include guards can only prevent multiple definitions **in a single translation unit** (a `.cpp` file). The individual units know nothing about each other, and so cannot possibly remove the multiple definition. This is why when the linker links the object files, it sees the multiple definitions still.

To solve this issue, change `common.hpp` to:

```
#pragma once

void some_function();
```

This tells the compiler that there is some code for `some_function`.
Then, add a file `common.cpp` that contains the code for the `common.hpp` header:

```
#include "common.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void some_function() {
    std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
}
```

Finally, change the `g++` command to:

```
g++ main.cpp common.cpp Thing.cpp -o main
```